# clearpath_turtlebot error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi .... i am working on multiple turtlebots and use the clearpath turtlebot package to move the turtlebots randomly ... while roslaunch turtlebot_rndmwalk  rndm_walk.launch there is an error occur
...................
error loading  tag:
file does not exist [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/openni_params.yaml]
XML is 
......................
i am using ros fuerte plzz anyone tell how i handle this error thanks ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60493/clearpath_turtlebot-error/) by [qubaish g](https://answers.ros.org/users/4502/qubaish-g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-12**:
What versions of packages are you using? Is everything from debian packages or some from source?

**Comment by [qubaish g](https://answers.ros.org/users/4502/qubaish-g/) on 2013-04-15**:
i obtained the package from this source http://www.ros.org/wiki/clearpath_turtlebot ..... i have been able to resolve the error given above . now i am confronted with another error that is "no device connected" . just want to ensure whether it requires kinect or not.

**Comment by [qubaish g](https://answers.ros.org/users/4502/qubaish-g/) on 2013-04-15**:
what i think , error is occurring because kinect is not connected to usb port .... also i want to ask is there any possibility to get kinect data from gazebo? .. have u run that package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Is you kinect camera hooked up to a USB 2.0 or USB 3.0? The Kinect does not work with a USB 3.0.

---

Originally posted by [MartinCote](https://answers.ros.org/users/20034/martincote/) with karma: 76 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0